# How to register an image manually (image registration)

Tags: c++, image, matlab, image-processing, image-manipulation

I'm converting code from Matlab to C++, and one of the functions that I don't understand is imtransform. I need to "register" an image, which basically means stretching, skewing, and rotating my image so that it overlaps correctly with another image.

Matlab's imtransform does the registration for you, but as I'm programming this in C++ I need to know what's been abstracted. What is the normal math involved in image registration? How can I go from 2 arrays of data (which make up images) to 1 array, which is the combined image overlapped?

Comment: You probably want to use a library like opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw C++ does not have any of the concepts you refer to built into it. However, there are many image processing libraries for C++ you can use that can do various transforms. [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) and [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) should be able to do layering, as well as some transforms.

Comment: thanks for the advice - I took a look but they didn't have what I was looking for. I managed to manually code it myself though :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use OpenCV within c++ and there are a lot of image processing tools and functions you can call and use.

The Registration module implements parametric image registration. The implemented method is direct alignment, that is, it uses directly the pixel values for calculating the registration between a pair of images, as opposed to feature-based registration.

The OpenCV constants that represent these models have a prefix `MOTION_` and are shown inside the brackets.

- Translation ( `MOTION_TRANSLATION` ) : The first image can be shifted ( translated ) by (x , y) to obtain the second image. There are only two parameters x and y that we need to estimate.
- Euclidean ( `MOTION_EUCLIDEAN` ) : The first image is a rotated and shifted version of the second image. So there are three parameters — x, y and angle . You will notice in Figure 4, when a square undergoes Euclidean transformation, the size does not change, parallel lines remain parallel, and right angles remain unchanged after transformation.
- Affine ( `MOTION_AFFINE` ) : An affine transform is a combination of rotation, translation ( shift ), scale, and shear. This transform has six parameters. When a square undergoes an Affine transformation, parallel lines remain parallel, but lines meeting at right angles no longer remain orthogonal.
- Homography ( `MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY` ) : All the transforms described above are 2D transforms. They do not account for 3D effects. A homography transform on the other hand can account for some 3D effects ( but not all ). This transform has 8 parameters. A square when transformed using a Homography can change to any quadrilateral.

Reference: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/db/d61/group__reg.html

This is an example I found very useful for image registration:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;

const int MAX_FEATURES = 500;
const float GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.15f;


void alignImages(Mat &im1, Mat &im2, Mat &im1Reg, Mat &h)

{


  Mat im1Gray, im2Gray;
  cvtColor(im1, im1Gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
  cvtColor(im2, im2Gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

  // Variables to store keypoints and descriptors
  std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
  Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;

  // Detect ORB features and compute descriptors.
  Ptr<Feature2D> orb = ORB::create(MAX_FEATURES);
  orb->detectAndCompute(im1Gray, Mat(), keypoints1, descriptors1);
  orb->detectAndCompute(im2Gray, Mat(), keypoints2, descriptors2);

  // Match features.
  std::vector<DMatch> matches;
  Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("BruteForce-Hamming");
  matcher->match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches, Mat());

  // Sort matches by score
  std::sort(matches.begin(), matches.end());

  // Remove not so good matches
  const int numGoodMatches = matches.size() * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT;
  matches.erase(matches.begin()+numGoodMatches, matches.end());


  // Draw top matches
  Mat imMatches;
  drawMatches(im1, keypoints1, im2, keypoints2, matches, imMatches);
  imwrite("matches.jpg", imMatches);


  // Extract location of good matches
  std::vector<Point2f> points1, points2;

  for( size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
  {
    points1.push_back( keypoints1[ matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    points2.push_back( keypoints2[ matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
  }

  // Find homography
  h = findHomography( points1, points2, RANSAC );

  // Use homography to warp image
  warpPerspective(im1, im1Reg, h, im2.size());

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Read reference image
  string refFilename("form.jpg"); 
  cout << "Reading reference image : " << refFilename << endl; 
  Mat imReference = imread(refFilename);


  // Read image to be aligned
  string imFilename("scanned-form.jpg");
  cout << "Reading image to align : " << imFilename << endl; 
  Mat im = imread(imFilename);


  // Registered image will be resotred in imReg. 
  // The estimated homography will be stored in h. 
  Mat imReg, h;

  // Align images
  cout << "Aligning images ..." << endl; 
  alignImages(im, imReference, imReg, h);

  // Write aligned image to disk. 
  string outFilename("aligned.jpg");
  cout << "Saving aligned image : " << outFilename << endl; 
  imwrite(outFilename, imReg);

  // Print estimated homography
  cout << "Estimated homography : \n" << h << endl; 

}
```

Comment: Hi again! Nice answer! I have taken the liberty to format your post so I could read it better. You had all the text formatted as code, which means each paragraph is on a single line and I needed to scroll far to the right to read. Any line starting with 4 spaces is considered a line of code. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) about the Markdown formatting that SO uses. A well formatted answer is much more helpful than a poorly formatted one!

Comment: You are right. sorry for the mistake 8 will edit it now